# How can I export an xmgrace graphic to Latex?

Tags: graphics, graphs

I´ts basically that, but I don´t want to be an PNG or JPEG format, because when I scaled it becomes ugly.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Can you export to pdf? Have you considered asking in the *xmgrace* community? I have never heard of it before.

Comment: You can export your final data from grace and use `pgfplots` to plot your data matching to the rest of your document.

Answer (score 2):

(QT)(X/M)Grace generally exports vector graphics to (E)PS, PDF, MIF, and SVG formats.

Each have their merits

**EPS may be the best choice** since its an old standard and many Latex packages expect its structure. (PostScript is "purer" but (E)PS can often be easily stripped of the (E))
Same as PDF you can play with resolution and fonts to get a high quality output
[image]

PDF may be easiest all rounder (**ensure it is vector** NOT jpg/png raster), However the fonts look crudely rasterised bitmaps so may have to play with many font settings, to get reasonable results.
[image]

*MIF not so useful for Latex as this is the FrameMaker Interchange Format so best for importing towards web/xml applications*
[image]

SVG possibly the best for quality data (just like MATLAB) as it can be manipulated as text, however that may reduce ease of use, since it looks like `Grace` exports lots of complex data without the standard structure, I got variable results trying to import e.g. MS browsers would not view it.
However you can manipulate and convert it with Inkscape / imagemagick as high quality graphics.
[image]

The ultimate choice will depend on intended uses and without some MWE to show how you apply them I suggest, with modern cheap storage, you hedge your bets and save in all 3 of these versatile vector formats.